# JNI_CreateJavaVM in Windows crashes with no error but works on MacOs

Tags: java, c++

I'm having a problem trying to create a JVM from C++ to run Java code in my C++ code.

I did some test in macOs and it works perfect, but in windows it compiles but when i run the code it exits without any output.

Below a have a piece of my code about the creation of the JVM.

````java
   JavaVMOption jvmopt[1];
   jvmopt[0].optionString = (char *)"-Djava.class.path=.";

   JavaVMInitArgs vmArgs;
   vmArgs.version = JNI_VERSION_1_2;
   vmArgs.nOptions = 3;
   vmArgs.options = jvmopt;
   vmArgs.ignoreUnrecognized = JNI_TRUE;

   cout << "START JVM \n";
   JavaVM *javaVM;
   JNIEnv *jniEnv;
   long flag = JNI_CreateJavaVM(&javaVM, (void **)&jniEnv, &vmArgs);
   cout << flag << "\n";

   if (flag == JNI_ERR)
   {
      cout << "Error creating VM. Exiting...\n";
      return 1;
   }
   cout << "\nJVM CREATED";

   (...)

   javaVM->DestroyJavaVM();```
````

I use this .bat to compile and execute the code.

Windows

```sh
@ECHO OFF
ECHO BUILDING 1/1

g++ ^
    -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_202\include" ^
    -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_202\include\win32" ^
    -L"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_202\lib"^
    -o jvmdemo.exe jvmdemo.cpp -ljvm


ECHO BUILDING [OK]

jvmdemo.exe
```

I use this bash to compile and execute the code in macOs and it works fine, it gives all outputs and creates the JVM.

MacOS

```sh
#!/bin/bash
echo "BUILDING 1/1"

g++  \
    -I/usr/include \
    -I$JAVA_HOME/include \
    -I$JAVA_HOME/include/darwin \
    -I$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/server/ \
    -rpath $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/server/ \
-o jvmdemo jvmdemo.cpp $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/server/libjvm.dylib 

echo "BUILDING [OK]"

./jvmdemo
```

As I said it works perfect on macOs, but somehow in windows it compiles but has no output when I run it, if i remove the `-ljvm` from the g++ it gives the error `` undefined reference to `_imp__JNI_CreateJavaVM@12' ``, it strange because it doesn't show even the simples `cout` but if i comment the line that creates the JVM it gives all outputs.

Any suggestion or help?

Comment: `vmArgs.nOptions = 3;` says that the options array contains 3 entries but the above code only allocates and initialises 1 entry.

Comment: That was just a typo from another test, with nOptions = 1 the error keeps occurring